# Granting access to S3 resources based on role name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

IAM [policy variables](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html) are quite cool and let you create generic policys to, for example, give users access to paths in an S3 bucket based on their username, like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": ["s3:GetObject","s3:PutObject","s3:DeleteObject"],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::fooCorp-user-files/${aws:username}/*"
        },
        {
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::fooCorp-user-files"
        }
    ]
}
```

My question is, how can this be done using roles (attached to EC2 instances) instead of user accounts?

I have a number of app servers with unique IAM user accounts that are linked to a generic policy similar to the one above. This isolates the files accessible by each user/app without creating multiple policies.

I want switch these servers to use [roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles.html) instead but there doesn't seem to be an equivalent IAM variable like `aws:rolename`.

[The docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html) indicate that when using a role assigned to an EC2 instance the `aws:username` variable isn't set and `aws:userid` is `[role-id]:[ec2-instance-id]` (which isn't helpful either).

This really seems like something you should be able to do.. or am I coming at this the wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been looking for the same and after a lot of searching my conclusion was that **it is not possible to use the role name as a variable in a IAM policy** (I'd love to be proven wrong though).

Instead, I tagged my role with a `name` and ended up with this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": ["s3:GetObject","s3:PutObject","s3:DeleteObject"],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::fooCorp-user-files/${aws:PrincipalTag/name}/*"
        },
        {
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::fooCorp-user-files"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

(Cross-posted to [AWS S3 IAM policy for role for restricting few instances to connect to S3 bucket based in instance tag or instance id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35718371/aws-s3-iam-policy-for-role-for-restricting-few-instances-to-connect-to-s3-bucket/35720454#35720454))

Instead of using `aws:SourceArn`, use `aws:userid`!

The [Request Information That You Can Use for Policy Variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html#policy-vars-infotouse) documentation that you mentioned has a table showing various values of `aws:userid` including:

> For **Role assigned to an Amazon EC2 instance**, it is set to `role-id:ec2-instance-id`

Therefore, you could use the **Role ID** of the role that is used to launch the Amazon EC2 instance to permit access OR the **Instance ID**.

For example, this one is based on a **Role ID**:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "SID123",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:userid": [
                        "AROAIIPEUJOUGITIU5BB6*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Of course, if you are going to assign permission based on a Role ID, then you can just as easily grant permissions within the Role itself.

This one is based on an **Instance ID**:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "SID123",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:userid": [
                        "*:i-03c9a5f3fae4b630a"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The Instance ID will remain with the instance, but a new one will be assigned if a new instance is launched, even from the same Amazon Machine Image (AMI).

Comment: In what way? The instance ID is one of the new, longer-length IDs being rolled out.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question; it's asking specifically about the role _name_.