# How can I allow an EC2 instance with an IAM role to set the instance health for itselt, only?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, autoscaling

I want to allow a script running on my EC2 instance to indicate when it is healthy to the autoscaling group.  To do so, I can run the following from my script:

```
aws --region $AWSREGION \
  autoscaling \
  set-instance-health \
  --instance-id $(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id) \
  --health-status Unhealthy
```

Before granting any special permissions to the IAM role, I get the following error (as I'd expect):

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the SetInstanceHealth operation: User: arn:aws:sts::ACCOUNTID:assumed-role/ROLENAME/i-INSTANCEID is not authorized to perform: autoscaling:SetInstanceHealth
```

I could add the following statement to my IAM role to get around this:

```
{
  "Action": [
    "autoscaling:SetInstanceHealth"
  ],
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Resource": "*"
}
```

But wouldn't that allow instances in this role to set instance health on all instances (assuming they know the instance id)?  I wouldn't want one compromised instance being able to take others out of their own ASGs.

Comment: This method might work: [Granting access to S3 resources based on role name](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35720528/174777). It also has a method for using the Instance ID.However, it is hard-coded rather than being a variable.

Answer (score 0):

The [Supported Resource-Level Permissions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/control-access-using-iam.html#resource-level-permissions-auto-scaling) documentation lists *Auto Scaling group* in the *Resource ARN* column, indicating you can restrict `autoscaling:SetInstanceHealth` by `Resource`.

The [IAM Policy Simulator](https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/) disagrees:

> This action does not support resource-level permissions

... but I've verified the following IAM policy permits finding members of auto-scaling groups, checking their CloudWatch metrics, and then setting instance health of members of *only one* auto-scaling group:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
      {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Action": [
              "autoscaling:SetInstanceHealth"
          ],
          "Resource": "arn:aws:autoscaling:REGION:ACCOUNT:autoScalingGroup:UUID:autoScalingGroupName/NAME"
      },
      {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Action": [
              "autoscaling:DescribeAutoScalingGroups",
              "cloudwatch:ListMetrics",
              "cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics"
          ],
          "Resource": "*"
      }
  ]
}
```