# S3 Cross Account Access With Role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I need to create a cross account role to access the resources of S3 bucket   from another aws account that I owns.

Please help me to implement this using the cross account IAM role without using Access or secret keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you have:

- Role A in Account A
- Instance A in Account A that is associated with Role A
- Bucket B in Account B

You wish to allow an application on Instance A to access the content of Bucket B.

The [Request Information That You Can Use for Policy Variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html#policy-vars-infotouse) documentation has a table showing various values of `aws:userid` including:

> For **Role assigned to an Amazon EC2 instance**, it is set to `role-id:ec2-instance-id`

Therefore, you could use the **Role ID** of the role associated with the Amazon EC2 instance to permit access OR the **Instance ID**.

For example, this bucket policy is based on a **Role ID**:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "SID123",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::MYBUCKET",
                "arn:aws:s3:::MYBUCKET/*"
            ],
            "Principal": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:userid": [
                        "AROAIIPEUJOUGITIU5BB6*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

To obtain the Role ID, use:

```
aws iam get-role --role-name ROLENAME
```

This bucket policy is based on an **Instance ID**:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "SID123",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::MYBUCKET",
                "arn:aws:s3:::MYBUCKET/*"
            ],
            "Principal": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:userid": [
                        "*:i-03c9a5f3fae4b630a"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The Instance ID will remain with the instance, but a new one will be assigned if a new instance is launched, even from the same Amazon Machine Image (AMI).

Of course, you'd probably want to restrict those permissions to just `s3:GetObject` rather than `s3:*`.

(This answer based on [Granting access to S3 resources based on role name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35711816/174777).)

Comment: Your both examples are identical - by mistake, I suppose?

Comment: @PeterKilczuk True! I've made an edit (to restore the Instance ID from a previous edit) that hopefully fixes it. Thank you.